# How to allow FTP on OpenVPN with NAT?

Tags: linux, centos, vpn, firewall, iptables

I'm using these iptables rules for my OpenVPN server with 1 NIC (eth0)

```
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

which of course is much too open.

But I would like to be able to use FTP through the VPN connection.

I assume I have to put

```
modprobe ip_conntrack
modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
```

in top of my iptables script.

But how should the actual iptables rules look like?

Comment: Active or passive mode ftp?  It looks to me right now as if passive mode, at least, should work.  Can you show us what happens when you try it?

Comment: @MadHatter : Yes, passive should work, but the problem seams to be active, according to this wikipedia article. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ftp#NAT_and_firewall_traversal

Comment: As I said, passive mode at least should work, and *imho* active as well, with the ruleset you've posted and those two modules applied.  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: You are right! I thought the problem was in the VPN, but apparently the FTP server was down =) If you copy/paste you last comment as answer, I will accept =)

Comment: OK, thanks.  I've added what might be a useful pointer or two about making the rules a little tighter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the rules you give above, both active and passive mode FTP should work right now.

If you want to be a bit more precise about accepting only ftp control and data connections, and assuming the client is on the OpenVPN interface, you could replace the two general accepts with

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```